# Testing child model with RSPEC and getting the error undefined method id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have two model classes in a "parent-chid" relationship, or association.

`organizations` is the parent table / model having the attributes: `id, organization_name, created_at and updated_at`.

`events` is the child table / model having the attributes: `id, event_description, host_name, created_at, updated_at and organization_id`.

The association between organizations and events records is `events.organization_id = organizations.id`, or as is specified in the model classes:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
...
  belongs_to :organization
...
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
...
  has_many  :events, :dependent => :destroy
...
end
```

The tests for `organizations` model and `organizations` controller runs without any errors. 
The test for `events` controller is not build yet. 
The app fully functional and is working without any errors.

The problem I have is that I cannot make the Events model test to pass.

Here is my code.

`factories/organizations`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :organization do
    organization_name { Faker::Company.name }
  end
  factory :invalid_organization, class: Organization do
    organization_name ''
  end
end
```

`factories/events`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    event_description { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3) }
    host_name { Faker::Internet.domain_name }
    organization = build(:organization)
    organization_id = organization.id
  end
end
```

I am trying to create an organization first and use the `id` for the `organization_id` attribute of the new `event` to be created.

And this is the file `event_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Event, type: :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    event = build(:event)
    expect(event).to be_valid
  end
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:event_description) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:host_name) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:organization_id) }
  it { is_expected.to belong_to(:organization) }
end
```

Basically I want to create first an `organization` and use this `id` to be assigned to `organization_id` when I am creating and `event`.

When running the test `rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb` I am getting this error:

```
/Users/levi/ror/events-handler/spec/factories/events.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `id' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Static:0x007febc03db798> (NoMethodError)
```

Don't know how to fix it or how to write a better test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `event` factory should look a bit different:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    event_description { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3) }
    host_name { Faker::Internet.domain_name }
    organization { build(:organization) } 
  end
end
```

Comment: Initially I got this error: organization_id: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Organization can't be blank. In order to eliminate this error I added this line in the organization factory: id { Faker::Number.number(5) } and after that the test passed successfully. Many thanks!

Comment: you shouldn't set random id for `organization`. Better option would be to actually `create` organization (instead of `build`)

Comment: When removing the id generation from organization factory and replacing in your solution the line organization { build(:organization) } with the line organization = FactoryGirl.create( :organization ) , I am getting the error: /Users/levi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find': Factory not registered: organization (ArgumentError)

Comment: should be just `organization { create(:organization) }`

Comment: It worked, many thanks, sorry for my confusion. Your solution also eliminated the warning DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::TestCase HTTP request methods will accept only
keyword arguments in future Rails versions. Which I got when generating the id.

Comment: No, sorry again, the deprecation . warning is still shown, but I am ok for the moment with these results.